# Caching WMS data

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, cache

I have an MXD created from a WMS server and I am using it as a basemap in a flex viewer app. In order to speed up rendering time I need to cache this. However I have been unsuccessful. After the scales have been created using Arcatalog map service properties the manage map server cache tiles fails to manage tiles at all extents and levels. Is there some other process I can do to help speed up rendering?

Comment: Ur trying to cache a WMS and then re serve as an ArcGIS server service or you want to create a WMTS? Is the data provider of the WMS ok with this?

Comment: This has your answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53512/arcgis-server-cache-from-outside-wms-service